# drawImage html5/javascript on webview android

Tags: javascript, android, html, android-webview

I'm trying to draw an image on a canvas with html5/javascript. In a browser it opens ok, but in the webview an emulator QVGA (320x240) it opens wrong.

Here is my code:

```
img.src = 'bobs.jpg';  
  img.onload = function() {
    ctx.drawImage(img,0,0, img.width, img.height);
}
```

[Here is the print screen of the emulator](https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-Uk3_QFTwMYo/UFeWBClHHVI/AAAAAAAAAJQ/anBfTCr4VXw/w417-h554-p-k/erro.png)

Why this error happens? Why the image does not display whole?